# Java delay before throwing ConnectException

Tags: java, exception, delay, throw, connectexception

I'm writing some code in Java to dowload stuff from urls and in my configuration some downloads should be handled by a proxy and others without it.

So I wrote this code (it works) to download all URL types but and I'd like to **reduce the delay time before a ConnectException is thrown** so the code can execute faster.

```
URL global_url = new URL("http://google.com");
Scanner sc = null;
try { 
    sc = new Scanner(global_url.openStream());
}
catch (ConnectException e) {
    try {
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.host");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "my.port");
        sc = new Scanner(global_url.openStream());
        System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "");
        System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "");
    }
    catch (ConnectException exc) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Right now it takes approx. **10s** before the exception is thrown and I'd like to **reduce this time to 2s or 3s max.**

Could I get some help?
Thanks !

Comment: What is the type of `global_url`? I'm assuning `URL`.

Comment: Of course global_url is of type URL yes ;)

Comment: This code doesn't work anyway. Those system properties are only read once, and in any case you aren't clearing them. You need to have a good look at using java.net.Proxy.

Comment: @EJP : I don't know why you are claiming this code doesn't work, it works perfectly on my program... when I have a local url where I don't need to use the proxy, I get the file instantly while when I want to have an "external" url, I catch the exception and get the file using the proxy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the timeout like this:

```
long connectTimeout = 3000;
URL global_url = new URL(urlPath);
URLConnection con = global_url.openConnection();
con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
```

where connectTimeout you can set as in milliseconds. As you need 3s timeout so set it as 3000.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I feed my Scanner with : 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(con.getInputStream()) ?

Comment: Maybe you should add that when the timeout is finished, it raises a SocketTimeoutException and not a ConnectExcepion ;)
Except from this point it works fine, thx again!!